# How to get value from JS form to write in input form php?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, echo, addeventlistener

I want to get the payment-total value to pass it on with php. Is there a way to insert it into `<input>` text to post it? Or is there any other way to do it?

```html
<input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum"> box 1

<select id="select" name="select">
    <option class="sum"></option>
    <option value="100" class="sum">option 0</option> 
</select>

<br/> Total: $<span id="payment-total">0</span>

<input id="payment-total" name="payment-total" type="text" readonly="readonly"  />

<script type="text/javascript">
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var checkboxesTotal = 0
var selectTotal = 0

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('change', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  total.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal + selectTotal
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You want to get it via javascript? And insert into the input? So when you submit a form it submits? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I would like it like <?php echo $payment-total ?> or give it to <input value="">

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to insert the value of payment total input type through Javascript.

Any value of Payment total can be given to input type Payment Total by using:

```
$('#payment-total').val(myVal);   // myVal is value of payment total 
                                  //  calculated in Javascript function....
```

If you want to do this with PHP, use Ajax and then put value in Payment Total.

Comment: I don't manage to get the value. I would like to $_POST the total added by JS that's why I want to get the value out of #payment-total. Or it would also be good if the input could somehow get the value